# Seeking Akavache documentation or examples

Tags: caching, windows-8, windows-phone

I discovered Akavache over the weekend and it looks like a nice highly recommended solution for caching items on both Win8 and WP8.

However, I cannot find any actual examples of or documentation for how to use it!

Does any one have any sample projects or docs I they can share?

Comment: sorry if this is not a "solve this code problem" type question, but I swear I can't find a single resource for this library. I find many praises for it but no proof anywhere that anyone has actually used it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm the author of Akavache. While there isn't any formal documentation other than the Readme, there are a few good examples of how to use it, I would read the ViewModels of these projects to see how it works:

- https://github.com/play/play-windows
- https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/AkavacheExplorer

However, I think the API is pretty self-explanatory, just hit `BlobCache.LocalMachine.` and see what Intellisense reveals :)

If you do have any questions though, ping me at paul@github.com and I'll be glad to help out.

Comment: thank you! example apps are just as good as docs, and I'll take a look at these for sure. many thanks again!

Comment: @Paul I would really appreciate if you could point us to an implementation of Akavache with Xamarin.Android/IOS. I would like to use it for cacheing objects received via http requests for certain amount of time. Thank you

Comment: I'd like to mainly know when to use the different packages like when I should use the akavache.mobile package (if at all)